# Ambari HDP Files View setup Connection Refused error 500

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, webhdfs

I installed Ambari HDP 2.3.6.0 on my ubuntu machine and i'm able to web login to the ambari and start all hdp services. However when I setup Files View setup accoriding to Hortonworks instructions, I'm getting an error '500 User: root is not allowed to impersonate admin'

I have setup hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups and hadoop.proxyuser.root.host according to HDFS setup instructions and also configured Files View

Please help as I'm new to this and just getting started.

Thanks